# How can I optimize filtering of large list in python?

Tags: python, list, filter

I have a csv with 400 000 rows. For each row I take all the previous rows, I filter them based on multiple conditions based on the current row and create some statistics. In total it takes too much time, so I am trying to find a way to speed it up.  So I am in between the things below:

1. a sqlite3 database
2. using pandas
3. using itetools.ifilter with the csv file

The following is the actual code I have, using the for loop as mentioned here:

```
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import csv
import numpy as np
import time
import itertools


# Functions

def get_shmeio_stats(data, reference_list):
    shmeio_stats = '-'
    if data:
        tally = (data.count(i) for i in reference_list)
        shmeio_stats = '-'.join(map(str, tally))
    else:
        shmeio_stats ='-'

    if shmeio_stats == '0-0-0':
                shmeio_stats ='-'
    return shmeio_stats


bet365_data_stats = []
shmeia_list = ['1', 'x', '2']
with open('BET365.csv', 'rb') as f:
    bet365_data = csv.reader(f)
    bet365_matches = list(bet365_data)[1:]

    start = time.time()
    for index, each_match in enumerate(bet365_matches):
        print index,
        start_each = time.time()
        id = index
#             print index
        protathlima, xronia, match_date, home, odd_1, odd_x, odd_2, away, score, score_1, score_2, simeio, favori, under_over = each_match
        previous_matches = bet365_matches[:index]

        home_1, home_x, home_2 = [], [], [] # home_1, home_x, home_2
        away_1, away_x, away_2 = [], [], [] # away_1, away_x, away_2
        home_all_yrs_protathlima, away_all_yrs_protathlima = [], [] # home_all_yrs_protathlima, away_all_yrs_protathlima
        home_forma_last_6_home, away_forma_last_6_away = [], [] # home_forma_last_6_home, away_forma_last_6_away
        home_forma_last_6_home_away, away_forma_last_6_home_away = [], [] # home_forma_last_6_home_away, away_forma_last_6_home_away
        akrivis_protathlima, akrivis_genika = [], [] # akrivis_protathlima, akrivis_genika
        mesos_oros_goal_home_last_6_home, mesos_oros_goal_away_last_6_away = [], [] # mesos_oros_goal_home_last_6_home, mesos_oros_goal_away_last_6_away

        for each_item in previous_matches:
            if each_item[3] == home:

                # home_1, home_x, home_2
                if each_item[4] == odd_1:
                    home_1.append(each_item[11])
                if each_item[5] == odd_x:
                    home_x.append(each_item[11])
                if each_item[6] == odd_2:
                    home_2.append(each_item[11])

                # home_all_yrs_protathlima
                if each_item[0] == protathlima:
                    home_all_yrs_protathlima.append(each_item[11])

                    # home_forma_last_6_home
                    if each_item[1] == xronia:
                        home_forma_last_6_home.append(each_item[11])
                        home_forma_last_6_home_away.append(each_item[11])
                        mesos_oros_goal_home_last_6_home.append(float(each_item[9]))

            if each_item[7] == home:
                if each_item[0] == protathlima:                    
                    # home_forma_last_6_home_away
                    if each_item[1] == xronia:
                        home_forma_last_6_home_away.append(each_item[11])

            if each_item[3] == away:
                if each_item[0] == protathlima:
                     # away_forma_last_6_away
                    if each_item[1] == xronia:
                        away_forma_last_6_home_away.append(each_item[11])

            if each_item[7] == away:

                # away_1, away_x, away_2
                if each_item[4] == odd_1:
                    away_1.append(each_item[11])
                if each_item[5] == odd_x:
                    away_x.append(each_item[11])
                if each_item[6] == odd_2:
                    away_2.append(each_item[11])

                # away_all_yrs_protathlima
                if each_item[0] == protathlima:
                    away_all_yrs_protathlima.append(each_item[11])

                     # away_forma_last_6_away
                    if each_item[1] == xronia:
                        away_forma_last_6_away.append(each_item[11])
                        away_forma_last_6_home_away.append(each_item[11])
                        mesos_oros_goal_away_last_6_away.append(float(each_item[10]))

            # akrivis_protathlima, akrivis_genika      
            if each_item[4] == odd_1 and each_item[5] == odd_x and each_item[6] == odd_2:
                akrivis_genika.append(each_item[11])
                if each_item[0] == protathlima:
                    akrivis_protathlima.append(each_item[11])

        stop_filter = time.time() - start_each
        print round(stop_filter, 6),

        # Calculate statistics

        # home_1, home_x, home_2
        home_1 = get_shmeio_stats(home_1, shmeia_list)
        home_x = get_shmeio_stats(home_x, shmeia_list)
        home_2 = get_shmeio_stats(home_2, shmeia_list)    

        # away_1, away_x, away_2
        away_1 = get_shmeio_stats(away_1, shmeia_list)
        away_x = get_shmeio_stats(away_x, shmeia_list)
        away_2 = get_shmeio_stats(away_2, shmeia_list)

        # home_all_yrs_protathlima, away_all_yrs_protathlima
        home_all_yrs_protathlima = get_shmeio_stats(home_all_yrs_protathlima, shmeia_list)
        away_all_yrs_protathlima = get_shmeio_stats(away_all_yrs_protathlima, shmeia_list)

        # home_forma_last_6_home, away_forma_last_6_away
        home_forma_last_6_home = get_shmeio_stats(home_forma_last_6_home[-6:], shmeia_list)
        away_forma_last_6_away = get_shmeio_stats(away_forma_last_6_away[-6:], shmeia_list)

        # home_forma_last_6_home_away, away_forma_last_6_home_away
        home_forma_last_6_home_away = get_shmeio_stats(home_forma_last_6_home_away[-6:], shmeia_list)
        away_forma_last_6_home_away = get_shmeio_stats(away_forma_last_6_home_away[-6:], shmeia_list)

        # akrivis_protathlima, akrivis_genika
        akrivis_protathlima = get_shmeio_stats(akrivis_protathlima, shmeia_list)
        akrivis_genika = get_shmeio_stats(akrivis_genika, shmeia_list)

        # mesos_oros_goal_home_last_6_home, mesos_oros_goal_away_last_6_away
        try:
            if mesos_oros_goal_home_last_6_home:
                    mesos_oros_goal_home_last_6_home = round(np.average(mesos_oros_goal_home_last_6_home[-6:]), 2)
            else:
                mesos_oros_goal_home_last_6_home = '-'
        except:
            mesos_oros_goal_home_last_6_home = '-'

        try:
            if mesos_oros_goal_away_last_6_away:
                    mesos_oros_goal_away_last_6_away = round(np.average(mesos_oros_goal_away_last_6_away[-6:]), 2)
            else:
                mesos_oros_goal_away_last_6_away = '-'
        except:
            mesos_oros_goal_away_last_6_away = '-'

        stop_function = time.time() - start_each
        print round(stop_function, 6),


        match_stats = [id, protathlima, xronia, match_date, home, odd_1, odd_x,
                odd_2, away, score, score_1, score_2, simeio,
                favori, under_over, home_1, home_x, home_2, away_1,
                away_x, away_2, home_all_yrs_protathlima, 
                away_all_yrs_protathlima, home_forma_last_6_home,
                away_forma_last_6_away, home_forma_last_6_home_away,
                away_forma_last_6_home_away, akrivis_protathlima, 
                akrivis_genika, mesos_oros_goal_home_last_6_home,
                mesos_oros_goal_away_last_6_away]

        bet365_data_stats.append(match_stats)

        stop_each = time.time() - start_each
        print round(stop_each, 6)

    stop = time.time() - start
    print 'Completed in:', stop

with open('BET365_stats_loop.csv', 'wb') as f:
    bet365_stats = csv.writer(f)
    bet365_stats.writerows(bet365_data_stats)
```

This is a part of my csv:
[image]

I have run it up to 180 000 rows, and each row took the maximum 0.3s.

Do you think that because of the amount of the data no matter what I choose the whole process will take too long ?

**Update:** At end I used a dictionary adding new keys when needed and updating them accordingly. It got really fast that way.

Comment: please elaborate how the processing looks like and what statistics you calculate. perhaps there's an algorithmic bottleneck rather than an implementational one.

Comment: Also, "too much time" is completely relative to what you are doing. Computing means of a subset of a column should be fairly quick in Numpy/Pandas; other things may take longer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're taking a huge hit because for every single iteration of your list up to index K, you're then iterating over the list up to index K-1 (`previous_matches`) **16 times** using `ifilter`. This is incredibly inefficient. You should just iterate over `previous_matches` once, and build all your lists (`home_1`, `home_x`, etc.) up as you iterate over it that single time.

So it should look like this:

```
 for index, each_match in enumerate(bet365_matches):
        id = index
        protathlima, xronia, match_date, home, odd_1, odd_x, odd_2, away, score, score_1, score_2, simeio, favori, under_over = each_match
        previous_matches = bet365_matches[:index]

        home_1 = []
        home_x = []
        home_2 = []
        # And the rest below
        for item in previous_matches:
            # home
            if item[3] == home:
                if item[4] == odd_1:
                    home_1.append(item)
                if item[5] == odd_x:
                    home_x = append(item)
                if item[6] == odd_2:
                    home_2 = append(item)
            # Same pattern for everything else

        home_x = get_shmeio_stats(home_x, shmeia_list)
        home_1 = get_shmeio_stats(home_1, shmeia_list)
        home_2 = get_shmeio_stats(home_2, shmeia_list)
        # And the rest
```

Comment: I did it the way you mention here and it got faster. What I don't really know is how much faster can it get. I mean what's the best that can be achieved with this amount of data, hours, minutes ?

Comment: @evil_inside That's kind of hard to answer without more information. How long is it taking now? Can you share a sample of the csv itself? I think it'd be helpful for folks trying to understand your algorithm.

Comment: I have added my code, a sample of my csv file and time that took each row.

Answer (score 0):

(This answer is very generic, because your question lacks specifics.)

Make sure you are not walking over the data twice. For example, if your processing looks like this:

```
output = [step2(i) for i in [step(1) j for j in get_list()]]
```

or

```
tmp = [step1(i) for i in get_list()]
tmp = [step2(i) for i in tmp]
tmp = [i for i in tmp if cond(i)]
#...
```

You would be better off either combining the steps into one:

```
output = [step2(step(1)) for i in get_list()]
```

or using [generator expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) instead of list comprehensions:

```
tmp = (step1(i) for i in get_list())
tmp = (step2(i) for i in tmp)
tmp = (i for i in tmp if cond(i))
#...
output = list(tmp) # if you need the output as a list
```